Java Initialize an int array, what happend in constructor
I know there are two ways to initialize an array in Java
int[] a = {1,2,3};

int[] a;
a = new int[]{1,2,3};

But why i cant use like this?
int[] a;
a = {1,2,3};

what happend in constructor? or where i can find java array constructor?
i can not find the detail of constrructor

There isn't a constructor.  This is just a fixed special part of Java syntax.

JLS 10.3. Array Creation: "An array is created by an array creation expression (§15.10.1) or an array initializer (§10.6)."

BTW there is a 3rd way to create an array: (indirectly) by calling a variable arity method or constructor

There is no 'magic constructor' here; instead, arrays are 'magic', in that there is no source file that defines their behaviour nor will you find e.g. .length, a property array objects have, in a source file. It also explains the 'magic' of why you can access arrays with foo[i] but no other things, and why arr.length "works" and is a read-only 'field' whereas that is not possible for anything else.
This magic is all defined in the Java Lang Spec.
Specifically, JLS §10.3 defines how you do it, and that is the place that decrees that you can omit the new int[] part if and only if you are writing the 'initializer' for a field or local variable whose type is declared as an array.
There is zero difference between:
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};

and
int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 3};

They produce bit-for-bit identical class files and indeed mean entirely the same thing. The compiler simply knows that you 'meant' to write the second form when it encounters the first; that shortcut is defined to exist only when defining the field/localvar, not when writing an assignment statement for it, hence why just a = {1, 2, 3}; is not allowed. There is no meaningful difference between those and:
int[] a;
a = new int[] {1, 2, 3};

either; AST wise they count as different but bytecodewise (and which lines of code are 'run'), there is zero difference.
